# Nuget publishing error: Failed to process request. 'A client version '4.1.0'

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I m publishing NuGet package. I ve installed latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Community. I get the following error:

> Failed to process request. 'A client version '4.1.0' or higher is
>   required to be able to push packages. Please contact support@nuget.org
>   to get more details.'.

Why latest Visual Studio cannot publish NuGet? How to fix it? The full build log is below:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyProject.NuGet, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  MyProject.NuGet -> C:\Users\User\Documents\MyProject\MyProject.NuGet\bin\Release\MyProject.NuGet.dll
1>   
1>  NuGet Packager 2.0.3
1>   
1>  Creating backup...
1>  Renamed MyProject.1.0.6.nupkg to MyProject.1.0.6.nupkg.bak
1>   
1>  Updating NuGet...
1>  The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'developmentDependency' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'releaseNotes, projectUrl, title, language, iconUrl, dependencies, frameworkAssemblies, tags, references, licenseUrl, summary, copyright, description' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'.
1>  Checking for updates from https://nuget.org/api/v2/.
1>  Currently running NuGet.exe 2.2.0.
1>  Updating NuGet.exe to 4.4.1.
1>   
1>  Creating package...
1>  Attempting to build package from 'Package.nuspec'.
1>  Id: MyProject
1>  Version: 1.0.6
1>  Authors: Boris Zinchenko
1>  Description: MyProject
1>  License Url: MyProject
1>  Project Url: MyProject
1>  Tags: MyProject
1>  Dependencies: 
1>  Added file 'lib\net20\MyProject.dll'.
1>  Added file 'tools\init.ps1'.
1>  Added file 'tools\install.ps1'.
1>  Added file 'tools\uninstall.ps1'.
1>  Successfully created package 'MyProject.1.0.6.nupkg'.
1>   
1>  Publishing package...
1>  Repository Url: https://www.nuget.org
1>   
1>  Pushing MyProject 1.0.6 to the NuGet gallery (https://www.nuget.org)...
1>  Failed to process request. 'A client version '4.1.0' or higher is required to be able to push packages. Please contact support@nuget.org to get more details.'. 
1>EXEC : The remote server returned an warning : (400) Bad Request..
1>  Pushing MyProject 1.0.6 to the NuGet gallery (https://www.nuget.org)...
1>  Failed to process request. 'A client version '4.1.0' or higher is required to be able to push packages. Please contact support@nuget.org to get more details.'. 
1>EXEC : The remote server returned an warning : (400) Bad Request..
1>   
1>  Exit Code: 0
1>   
1>  Build Exit Code: -1
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Update**

After valuable advise by @Alexei Levenkov, I ve updated NuGet version using command: `Install-Package NuGet.VisualStudio`. Surprisingly, it did not make any effect on my error and the error still remains the same. The log of update from NuGet console is below.

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 4.5.0.4685
Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package NuGet.VisualStudio

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0' with respect to project 'MyProject', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0'
Gathering dependency information took 20.7 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0'
Retrieving package 'NuGet.VisualStudio 4.5.0' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuget.visualstudio/4.5.0/nuget.visualstudio.4.5.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuget.visualstudio/4.5.0/nuget.visualstudio.4.5.0.nupkg 524ms
Installing NuGet.VisualStudio 4.5.0.
Adding package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0' to folder 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MyProject\packages'
Added package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0' to folder 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MyProject\packages'
Added package 'NuGet.VisualStudio.4.5.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'NuGet.VisualStudio 4.5.0' to MyProject
Executing nuget actions took 5.01 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:07.1699206
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours and despairing with all standard NuGet advises, I ve found in my project folder old NuGet.exe 2.2.0. Why exe file is installed and stored together with NuGet deployment code and why this file is not automatically updated with NuGet.VisualStudio installation for this project, I have no idea. Probably, it is either NuGet bug or NuGet.VisualStudio bug.

Whatever the reason for NuGet.exe not being updated automatically, I downloaded latest NuGet.exe from NuGet.org site and just replaced it in my project manually. After this manual replacement everything repaired and published successfully.

Because I ve used standard Microsoft project template for NuGet publishing earlier and now upgraded to new Visual Studio in a standard way, I m sure that I went a common route, which many others may repeat to evidence same problem. I think Visual Studio team must acknowledge it as a bug and devise a patch.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT, Thank you for the prompt comment. I was vague marking it as an answer because the recipe is quite silly and ugly. But since nobody suggests any better still, I will mark it perhaps. Principally, something must be done to avoid this manual manipulation. I see it especially wrong that NuGet exe is stored as essential part of publishing project, which is both inefficient from code management viewpoint and unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not get updated version of NuGet. I assume one that comes with VS is less than 4.1 and it sounds like www.nuget.org now requires higher version.

To update NuGet:

- see instruction at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools (CLI version)
- for one inside VS   https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.VisualStudio - run following in "Package Manager" window of VS:

  ```
  Install-Package NuGet.VisualStudio -Version 4.5.0
  ```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I m wondering what log messages mean: "1>  Currently running NuGet.exe 2.2.0. 1>  Updating NuGet.exe to 4.4.1." From the log one may guess that NuGet was already updated. I will check version. Again, it is the LATEST VS2017!

Comment: Ridiculously, very reasonable advise by @Alexei Levenkov did not work. I still receive the same error after successful NuGet update. I will update the description of this issue to show also NuGet update log.

Comment: I was using octopack and have got the same error and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those that arrive here by way of a search based on an error message experienced while trying to publish a Powershell module to PSGallery, try the steps below.

```
# This should get you the current version of PowershellGet
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -Scope AllUsers

# But just in case...
Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
```

Open a new session.

```
Import-Module PowershellGet -Force

# Make sure you have the expected version of the module
Get-Module PowershellGet

# Run your publish commands again 
<YOUR_PUBLISH_COMMAND>
```

Some of these steps may be unnecessary, but this is how I solved the problem on my machine.

If you find yourself battling this issue in a CI/CD pipeline, you may need to add a step to install the module for the build-agent user (or equivalent). I had to do this even after installing PowershellGet for all users.

Here's a related blog post: https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2019/03/01/quick-update-on-psgallery-publishing/